# I can't user guild for my bot (I'm at the beginning with discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

When i try to run this code:

```
bot.sendMessage({
  to: channelID,
  message: message.guild.name
});
```

I got Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
This error happen always i try to use guild.

Here's my full bot code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
var verificationUser;
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 21) == '<@' + bot.id + '>') {
        var args = message.substring(22).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'help':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: "Istruction for make the verification:\n1 - Mention me and write 'verification'.\n2 - Mention me your Mazebert id.\n3 - Play a suicide play without build tower, just waiting the death.\n4 - Mention me and text 'check'.\n5 - Finish!"
                });
                break;
            case 'verification':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: "<@"+ userID + ">For starting the verification you have to write your Mazebert id. You can take it in your profile, is the numerical code in the url."
                });
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: message.guild.name
                });
                verificationUser = userID;
            break;
         }
     }
});
```

I'm at the start with discord bot in js so i can't understand why i get this error.

Comment: When using SO, rather than editing the title of your question, accept the answer you found most useful. You can do so by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of using on message is like this

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
```

and not

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
```

As you are specifying extra parameters which would return undefined if you try to access them later on.

And you can check the properties of the message object [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message)

Comment: Thanks now i try.

Comment: Just to clarify, standard function notation is okay; the parameters are the issue with the original code.